# How to compare multiple values in list.where

Tags: flutter

I want to multiple values in a List.

For example I have below json which I decode in a customList List :

```
 "cars": [
{ "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
{ "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
{ "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
 ]
```

I want to get the updated list when user searches for some keyword. The keywords can also contain name of car or model. How can I do this. Below is the code where I am successfully searching in names only.

```
  List<Cars> updatedList = List<Cars>();

  _onChanged(String value) {
    setState(() {
       updatedList = carsList
      .where((string) => string.name.contains(value.toLowerCase()))
      .toList();
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do u want display the result by searching !? Or separate a list after searching ??

Comment: @NaveenAvidi Separate a list

Comment: I updated my answer ! Check if its useful !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Map carsMap = {
    "cars": [
      {
        "name": "Ford",
        "models": ["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]
      },
      {
        "name": "BMW",
        "models": ["320", "X3", "X5"]
      },
      {
        "name": "Fiat",
        "models": ["500", "Panda"]
      }
    ]
  };

  List<Map> carsList = [];
  String query1 = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    carsList = carsMap['cars'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Seperate List'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 10, 5, 10),
            child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
              TextField(
                  onChanged: (s) {
                    query1 = s;
                  },
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: 'Filter Seacrh...',
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
                          onPressed: () {
                            showFiltered();
                          }))),
              ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: carsList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (con, ind) {
                    return  ListTile(
                            title: Text(carsList[ind]['name'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                )));
                  })
            ])));
  }

  showFiltered() {
    List<Map> updatedList = carsList.where(
        (m) => m.toString().toLowerCase().contains(query1.toLowerCase())).toList();

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (con) {
          return Dialog(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: updatedList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (con, ind) {
                    return ListTile(
                        title: Text(updatedList[ind]['name'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                            )));
                  }));
        });
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]